# How to get geo-location based on list of ip addresses in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, geolocation, kibana, geoip

I have a bunch of log files that are already Indexed in Elastic. Is there a way I can create a new field within each JSON document of my index and run something to get the geo-location of each IP address?

I know about Logstash, but I would like to keep this in Elastic. Is that possible, if so, how?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you this nice tutorial :

[How To Map User Location with GeoIP and ELK (Elasticsearch, Logstash, and Kibana)](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-map-user-location-with-geoip-and-elk-elasticsearch-logstash-and-kibana)

I hope you can make it.